# GPS Device Attached to Linux Mint 15

Tags: linux, linux-mint, usb, devices

I purchased a Silvercrest GPS device from Lidl recently, but the software that came with it is a tad "underpowered" to say the very least and has no Linux support. I'm attempting to get at the raw data on the device myself to write something which I can use in Linux and not have to rely on my Windows machine and the exe that came with it, but I'm not too sure where to start to get access to the device.

As far as I can see it's a rebranded Targa device but can't find any more information on the web. (It's not a laptop GPS module or anything, its a simple outdoor GPS unit that I need to get the data off via USB after a trip out with it).

When I plug it in I get the following from `dmesg`, I hope someone can point me in the right direction as to how to interact with this thing.

```
[ 156.076046] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[ 156.208903] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=10d6, idProduct=1101
[ 156.208907] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 156.208910] usb 2-1: Product: Media Player
[ 156.208912] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: USB 
[ 156.208913] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: \xffffffe8\xffffffa7\xffffff9b\xffffffa7\xffffff9b \xffffffe8\xffffffbf\xffffffa6\xffffffbf\xffffffa6 \xffffffe7\xffffff83\xffffffb6\xffffff83\xffffffb6 \xffffffe8\xffffffa7\xffffff93\xffffffa7\xffffff93 \xffffffec\xffffff87\xffffff8d\xffffff87\xffffff8d \xffffffe2\xffffff88\xffffff8f\xffffff88\xffffff8f \xffffffe1\xffffff84\xffffffa4\xffffff84\xffffffa4 \xffffffe2\xffffffac\xffffffa2\xffffffac\xffffffa2 \xffffffee\xffffffb4\xffffff91\xffffffb4\xffffff91 \xffffffe4\xffffffb9\xffffff93\xffffffb9\xffffff93 \xffffffee\xffffffb4\xffffff91\xffffffb4\xffffff91 \xffffffe5\xffffff95\xffffff93\xffffff95\xffffff93 \xffffffe3\xffffffa8\xffffff91\xffffffa8\xffffff91 \xffffffe2\xffffff94\xffffff9c\xffffff94\xffffff9c \xffffffec\xffffff8a\xffffffb7\xffffff8a\xffffffb7 \xffffffe2\xffffff91\xffffffb8\xffffff91\xffffffb8
[ 156.212270] scsi5 : usb-storage 2-1:1.0
[ 157.213333] scsi 5:0:0:0: Direct-Access USB Media Player 2.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[ 157.214101] sd 5:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[ 157.226457] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

Answer (score 0):

After attaching, do

```
$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdc
```

and mount the partition(s) to see what's there.